# Make Navbar links move along the navbar instead of wrapping when width decreases

Tags: jquery, html, css

In full screen the Navbar links are laid out horizontally

[image]

However when the width changes they become like this

[image]

How do I make it so that they move over to the left when width changes while remaining horizontal?

HTML

```
<nav>
<h1 id=>Nav</h1> <div id="NHide">   
<ul>
    <li><a class="NavL" href="#slide1" title="Sample Text">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="NavL" href="#slide2" title="Sample Text">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="NavL" href="#slide1" title="Sample Text">Slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="NavL" href="#slide1" title="Sample Text">Slide 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#NHide{
position:absolute;
left:77%;
top:0%;    
}   

nav {
position: fixed;
z-index:1;    
font-size: 24px;
width: 100%;
line-height: 48px;
height: 48px;
background: #000;
text-align: left;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
} 

ul { 
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float:left;
}

li {
display:inline-block;
}

.NavL {
display: block;
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Either use `li {  float: left;}`  or `li {display: table-cell;white-space: nowrap;}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt this CSS

```
#NHide{
  position:absolute;
  left:77%;
  top:0%;    
}
```

to

```
#NHide{
  float:right
}
```

or (but the previous is better)

```
#NHide{
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
}
```

Since you said it always had to be located 77% from the left, it would wrap around, because your nav is too big to be on one line, but also 77% from the left.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please share a working example on for example http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

You want to fix your links to the right side of the nav bar, to do this just set `right: 0` and remove the `left: 77%`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4a3s2ht/)

```
#NHide{
    position: absolute;
    right 0;
    top: 0%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your style

```
#NHide
{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0%;    
}   
h1#headnav
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:-28px;
}
```

and add in your code

```
<h1 id="headnav">Nav</h1>
```